# Error: Insufficient values in manual scale. 24 needed but only 1 provided?

Tags: scrnaseq, seurat

folks.

Can you give me idea about an issue that I encountered?
I ran single-cell RNA sequencing data using Suerat in R, and when I tried to draw violin plot, there is an error as below.

> VlnPlot(tumors, "Cd79a", "Foxp3", "CD14")

Error: Insufficient values in manual scale. 24 needed but only 1 provided.

Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.

However, I can draw the violin plot for Cd79a. The problem happened to only several genes. I haven't solved this problem yet. Do you know what should we do?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must supply genes (or features) as a vector, not individually:

```
VlnPlot(tumors, c("Cd79a", "Foxp3", "CD14"))
```

By the way it is probably `Cd14`, not `CD14`.

Comment: Thank you. I learned a lot from you. Such a stupid mistake:)